# CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid magento error

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

using everst theme and trying to upload megamenu extension and getting this error need help.....
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section

Answer (score 0):

what all you need to do is paste the extension key in link : http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Than copy the extension files to root of the site

note : Take backup of files and database before doing any major changes

Comment: thanks for reply but i am uploading it through my laptop that's why i dont have key for this extension just has file

Comment: @HamzaNaseer can you give me a link of extension which is present in `magento connect site`......

Comment: i just got solution we have just to add zip of extension file in root directory of site and it will automatically added in your theme.

Comment: @HamzaNaseer  if you upload extracted zip folder files to root of the site, than it will work, if you just upload zip file, than i dont think it will work....

Comment: also please accept this answer if you got solution ..... as here  : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow